# Double join in Doctrine Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I deployed the FOSUserBundle and added to it a Group entity to have users' groups. Now i'd like to know how I can select one group of users for a variable in an other entity.

this is my variable:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="technician", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $technician;
```

i'd like the technician not to be just a User but belong to the technician Group which is the group with id "1".

Comment: I can't unterstand your sentence. Especially what does 'variable' mean ?

Comment: you need a manyToMany relationship, with accessors on both sides.

Comment: What @DevDonkey said. But I should note that you don't seem to have a firm grasp on the basics of relations, so I would recommend reading up on that. If you haven't yet Symfony has a great book with a chapter that covers all of this.